# No permission to access APN settings

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, crashlytics, logcat

I'm facing this issue in my android studio logcat.

java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to access APN settings
at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.checkPermission(TelephonyProvider.java:3947)
at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.checkPermissionCompat(TelephonyProvider.java:3964)
at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.query(TelephonyProvider.java:2927)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1379)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1475)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:278)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)

How to access APN settings?

Comment: Can you better describe what you're trying to do? Also add any relevant code to your question.

Comment: What is APN. ??